# Cisco ASA 5505 8.0(5): specifying IPSec mode in the tunnel-group or group-policy

Tags: cisco-asa, ipsec

Documentation states that you can (I'm assuming) *globally* disable aggressive mode with:

`isakmp am-disable`

Not exactly clear on the behavior when two peers are negotiating phase 1 in Cisco land, but in other firewalls, you usually can specific whether to use Main or Aggressive on each tunnel configuration; not exactly sure how to do this with an ASA 5505.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phase 1 mode can be customized in the crypto map for the individual peer.

```
crypto map tunnel-name 1 set peer 31.54.21.54
crypto map tunnel-name 1 set match address tunnel-acl
....
crypto map tunnel-name 1 set phase1-mode [aggressive|main]
```

Comment: ah, ok great...